# Target and command on dotnet csproj to run code coverage and generate report?

Tags: .net, .net-core, msbuild, xunit, msbuild-task

To collect coverage reports I am running the next commands from the solution folder:

```
dotnet test --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage"
reportgenerator -reports:Project.Tests\TestResults\66e8839d-6844-4b8a-8067-dc9c32abed5d\coverage.cobertura.xml  -targetdir:coverage
coverage\index.htm
```

What is the best way to automatize this local procedure?

---

We may include it as a command in `.csproj` such as:

```xml
<Target Name="cover">
    <Exec Command='dotnet test --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage"' />
</Target>
```

...and then we can run it with `dotnet build -t:cover`

Now I need to pass the generated XML coverage report, e.g. `TestResults\66e8839d-6844-4b8a-8067-dc9c32abed5d\coverage.cobertura.xml` to the `reportgenerator` command. How can we achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

This solution does not directly answer my question, but it was the best workaround that I found.
I end up building next batch file to run those commands.

```
::
:: Set path to test project folder
::
SET TestFolder=FireMapper.Test\TestResults
::
: Run coverage
::
dotnet test --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage"
::
: Get the path for the most recent coverage results folder
::
FOR /F "delims=|" %%I IN ('DIR "%TestFolder%\*.*" /B /O:D') DO SET NewestPath=%%I
::
: Generate HTML report for latter coverage results
::
reportgenerator -reports:%TestFolder%\%NewestPath%\coverage.cobertura.xml -targetdir:coverage
::
: Open the browser for coverage report index.htm
::
coverage\index.htm
```